# How many Apache Camel queues do I need?

Tags: configuration, apache-camel

I have a system with 15 services.  I'm new to camel and JMS remoting.  With 15 services I thought I should have one incoming queue per Service.

However, it seems that a queue can only bind to one interface:

```
org.apache.camel.example.server.Treble implements two interfaces     
org.apache.camel.example.server.Multiplier and org.apache.camel.example.server.Divider. I bind the two interfaces to the same JMS queue: jms:queue:numbers

<bean id="multiplier" class="org.apache.camel.spring.remoting.CamelServiceExporter">
          <property name="uri" value="jms:queue:numbers" />
          <property name="service">
                 <bean class="org.apache.camel.example.server.Treble" />
          </property>
          <property name="serviceInterface"  value="org.apache.camel.example.server.Multiplier" />
   </bean>
<bean id="divider" class="org.apache.camel.spring.remoting.CamelServiceExporter">
          <property name="uri" value="jms:queue:numbers" />
          <property name="service">
                 <bean class="org.apache.camel.example.server.Treble" />
          </property>
          <property name="serviceInterface" value="org.apache.camel.example.server.Divider" />
   </bean>
```

I found only the first binding(org.apache.camel.example.server.Multiplier) works. On the client side, I get a proxy of org.apache.camel.example.server.Divider and call divide(). The message can reach the server side. But when Camel tries to process the message, camel only cache the proxy of the first interface binding to  jms:queue:numbers. So it failed to process the message and throw an exception

So does that mean if I want to use jms remoting with camel I'll need a 2 queues (in/Out)/class?  Is that expensive?

Answer (score 1):

If you need all your services to use the same incoming end point then use the router http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html

Comment: thanks for the comment, but no my Services will not have the same data inputs.  They all have different data inputs.